# List of Deliveries and Create Delivery POSTMATE API having same URL

Tags: postmates

In PM Documentation URL of create and list of deliveries are same i.e, vi/customer/customerid/deliveries

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are but this is fine. The method you use for the api call will determine the response you get.

If you want a list of deliveries use the **GET** method.

If you want to create a delivery use the **POST** method.